# How to read comma delimited data from txt file to struct

Tags: c, struct, delimiter, file-handling

I have text file which have the following content

[inputfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9NgP.png)

I have used a function to get data from the input file which is comma delimited.
I want to read data from it and want to remove comma and store the data to Struct Resistor_struct.
I have tried the following code.

'''

```
#include<stdio.h>

//functions header
int blown_ressistors();


struct resistor_struct
{
    char ID_LEN[5];
    char id;
    float max_poewr; 
    int resistance;
};

struct resistor_struct rs[100];

int blown_ressistors()
{
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
        
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(fp, "%s[^,], %d[^,], %f[^,]",rs[i].ID_LEN,rs[i].resistance, rs[i].max_poewr)!=EOF)
        {
            
            printf("%s\t", rs[i].ID_LEN);
            printf("%d\t", rs[i].resistance);
            printf("%d\t\n", rs[i].max_poewr);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        perror("Input.txt: ");
    }
```

'''

output
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqxdW.png)

Comment: What *specific* problem do you have with the code? Wrong values? Crash? Nothing happens? Also, what debugging did you do and where do you find that thing first start to go wrong?

Comment: Output image is added

Comment: And please do not post text as images. Copy it directly as text into the question. Please read [ask].

Comment: `%s` stops at a whitespace. It appears you think it will read something like `"A R"`. It will not as it will read `A` and then stop when it sees the space.

Comment: yeah so i need something else?

Comment: `"%s[^,],` will read a string and then try to match a literal `[^,],`.  That is almost certainly not what you want, since the `%s` will consume everything up until a whitespace, which is not a `[`, so the `[` is guaranteed to not match.

Comment: Instead of `while( scanf(...) != EOF)`, it would be much more accurate to write `while( scanf(...) == 3`.  WIth your current code, `scanf` is never able to return values other than 1, 0, or EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to compare the value returned from scanf with EOF.
In your case, the format string is such that `scanf` can never match more than 1 conversion specifier, since `%s[^,],` is trying to match the literal input string `[^,],` but the `[` is guaranteed not to match since the first character that scanf will stop consuming for the `%s` is whitespace.  And `[` is not whitespace.   Try something like:

```
while(fscanf(fp, " %4[^,], %d, %f", rs[i].ID_LEN, &rs[i].resistance, &rs[i].max_poewr) == 3 )
```

but note that this will behave oddly on whitespace in the first column. You *might* want to try: `" %4[^, \t\n] , %d, %f"`, but quite frankly the better solution is to *stop* *using* *scanf*.  Even with something trivial like this, your behavior will be undefined on an input like `foo, 9999...9999` (where the 2nd column is any value that exceeds the capacity of an `int`).  Just stop using `scanf`.  Read the data and parse it with `strtol` and `strtod`.